# Nuxt Store - Can´t get all values in commit

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In Vuex i try to send some values to a store, like this.

```
 getStorage(
        { commit },
        name: String | undefined = undefined,
        objectA: ObjectA | undefined = undefined,
        objectB: ObjectB | undefined = undefined
    ) {
        if (selectedItinerary) {
            commit('setA', objectA, objectB)
        } else if (name) {
            commit('setB', name)
        }
    },
```

The problem: Only get name value, objectA and objectB return undefinied.

So: Somebody say what's wrong? Maybe can only send one param?

**UPDATE 1**

Calling dispatch

```
this.$store.dispatch('business/getLocalStorage', {
     name: this.name,
})
```

Store

```
getLocalStorage({ commit }, item) {
    if (item.name) {
        commit('setLocalStorageItinerary', item.name)
    }
}

setLocalStorageItinerary(state, { name }: { name: string }) {
    if (name) {
        const itinerary = new LocalStorage()
        itinerary.name = name
        state.itinerary = itinerary
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getStorage` is an action, [which receive the Vuex context as the first argument and a payload as the second](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions), just wrap your values up inside an object *before* passing it as the payload.

eg.

```
somewhere in your app...

let payload = {
  name: someValue,
  objectA: someObject,
  objectB: someOtherObject
}

this.$store.dispatch('getStorage', payload)
```

```
actions.js

getStorage({ commit }, payload) {
  if (selectedItinerary) {
    commit('setA', payload.objectA, payload.objectB)
  } else if (payload.name) {
    commit('setB', payload.name)
  }
}
```

It isn't clear from your example where `selectedItinerary` is defined, but I think you get the gist from the above.

Comment: With your example, payload.objectA returns undefined. Maybe need await in commit?

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code to really help. Where are you defining your properties?

Comment: I update question with more code.

Comment: Your updated example looks fine to me- if ```this.name``` is defined at the point where you pass it to your dispatch method, it should be accessible within your action. You could try replacing ```this.name``` with a static string (eg. 'test') to confirm everything else is working correctly, and let us know the outcome.

Comment: If a a replace with static string returns also undefined, it's very strange. I updated also question with setLocalStorage Itinerary function

Comment: In the update provided, you're destructuring a static string. ```commit('setLocalStorageItinerary', item.name)``` passes a static string to ```setLocalStorageItinerary(state, { name }: { name: string })```, which is trying to extract a property named ```name``` from the string you've passed in. That won't work my friend! Change to ```setLocalStorageItinerary(state, name: string)```.

Comment: Last question. Why if i try to do something like this 


 setLocalStorageItinerarySpots(
  state,
  selectedItinerary: LocalStorage,
  spots: any[]
 ) {


Return error saying that can´t assing to type mutation?

Comment: Similar to your previous issue. ```setLocalStorageItinerarySpots``` is a Vuex mutation, which receives the Vuex state as it's first argument, and a _single_ payload as the second. You can't pass ```selectedItinerary``` and then ```spots```. You've had to wrap the 2 up into a single object, and pass that object as the second argument. Have a read up on Vuex docs.